# Jquery variable returns null

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a wordpress shop right now and trying to implement a currency converter. So in the cart table is a dropdown list of available currencies.

When clicked the price should show up in that currency. Simple enough...

Here is part of the php with the list:

```
<section class="currency-converter-form" style="display:none;">

        <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="convert_to_field">
        <select name="currency" id="currency" class="currency_to" rel="convert_currency_to" >
            <option value="gbp" >GBP - British Pound Sterling</option>
            <option value="usd" >USD - US Dollar</option>
            <option value="aud" >AUD - Australian Dollar</option>
            <option value="cad" >CAD - Canadian Dollar</option>
            <option value="jpy" >JPY - Japanese Yen</option>
            <option value="nzd" >NZD - New Zealand Dollar</option>
            <option value="rub" >RUB - Russian Ruble</option>
            <option value="chf" >CHF - Swiss Franc</option>
        </select>
        </p>
```

Here is what I have as the jquery so far:

```
jQuery( function( $ ) {

$( document ).on( 'click', '.currency-converter-button', function() {
    $( '.currency-converter-form' ).slideToggle( 'slow' );


    return false;
}).on( 'change', function() {

    var currency = $( "#currency" ).val();

    console.log(currency);

    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: currency_conversion.ajaxurl,
    data: {
        action: 'get_conversion',
        currency
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});

    });$( '.currency-converter-form' ).hide();
});
```

Here the target `php` just to test the thing:

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_conversion', 'get_conversion' );



function get_conversion() {

 $to = $_POST['currency'];

 echo json_encode($to);}
```

I basically tried to use code already existing in wordpress an adjusted it. I would be happy if the alert would give me the selcted currency, but it returns 0.

I googled a lot and tried different things to no avail.  I would appriciate any help here.

Comment: What are some of the things you have tried?

Comment: I tried it with the $post method. I tried to save the values in an array variable. I know using existing code and adjusting it doesn't really help me to fully understand what is essentially going on, but it seemed to be the easiest and fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem in your code, but it's definitely one: the currency value inside the data that is passed to PHP has no key. The correct data to pass would then be:

```
data: {
    action: 'get_conversion',
    currency: currency
},
```

With this, PHP should now be able to access `$_POST['currency']` to get the currency value unless there are other problems.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know the code is messy right now. Unfortunately the problem seems to be elsewhere.